# Stone-Čech compactification is extremally disconnected.

Tags: general-topology, compactification

If $X$ is a discrete topological space, one can realize its Stone-Čech compactification [by means of ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#Construction_using_ultrafilters).

The compactification can be characterized in terms of [its universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#Universal_property_and_functoriality). I want to know if there is a "direct" proof of the fact that the Stone-Čech of a discrete space is an [extremally disconnected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space), by using "only" its universal property. That is, without appealing to any of its concrete realizations.

An extremally disconnected space is a space such that the closure of every open set is clopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $O$ is open in $\beta D$ (where $D$ is discrete), let $f: D \to \{0,1\}$ be the function that sends points in $O \cap D$ to $0$ and all other points to $1$; this is a continuous function as $D$ is discrete so the universal property tells us that there is a (unique)  $\beta f: \beta D \to \{0,1\}$ that extends $f$. [As $O$ is open and $D$ is dense, $\overline{O \cap D} = \overline{O}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982148) and as $f[O \cap D]=\{0\}$ we get that $\beta f [\overline{O}]= \{0\}$ as well, and we can show that $\overline{O}=(\beta f)^{-1}[\{0\}]$, a clopen set.

Comment: "We can show $\overline{O}=(\beta f)^{-1}\{0\}$": define $K:=\beta D\setminus\overline{O}$. $K$ is open; so is $(\beta f)^{-1}\{0\}$. If there is $x\in K$ with $\beta f(x)=0$ then it follows there is a neighbourhood $G$ of $x$ with $\beta f(G)=\{0\}$. We know $G\cap D$ is nonempty and also disjoint from $O\cap D$, so $\beta f(G\cap D)=f(G\cap D)=\{1\}$ yet $\beta f(G\cap D)\subseteq \beta f(G)=\{0\}$ so we have a contradiction. It follows that there is no $x\in K$ with $\beta f(x)=0$, and from this it is clear that $\overline{O}=(\beta f)^{-1}\{0\}$