# If X is a topological space, U is open in X, A is dense in X, then closure A∩U=closure U

Tags: general-topology

If X is a topological space, U is open in X, A is dense in X, then closure A∩U=closure U

I am stuck on the backward direction. The forward direction is easy since the intersection of A and U is a subset of U so that is true for their closures.

Comment: Apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3981623/4280) with a $K=A$. Use that $\operatorname{cl}(A)=X$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is in $\overline U$, and $G$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, then $U\cap G$ is also open (finite intersection of open sets) and non-empty (as $x \in \overline U$ and $G$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$) and thus intersects the dense set $A$, so $A\cap U$ intersects $G$, as $(U \cap G)\cap A = G \cap (A \cap U)$.

As $G$ was arbitrary, $x \in \overline{A \cap U}$ and the inclusion has been shown.